# SQL Replacing of values & select statement issues

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, substring

I am a newbie to both stackoverflow and SQL, so I do hope for your understanding ! Recently I have faced many SQL issues and I do hope some help could be provided to aid me. This is because I have tried sourcing for information, some did answer to my problems, but gave me more problems after that.
Firstly, I have seen a recent post by user javascriptstress in his replacement of values in a column. In my issue, I was working on credit card details in SQL whereby I had to censor the digits on the user's credit card values, which will show a result of **xxxxxxxxxxxx2345** instead of '2734948533562345' for Visa card. However by using SUBSTRING and LEN I am unable to get the values hidden. Due to the fact that not all credit cards have 16 digits, I have faced the problem of only providing the last 4 digits of the credit card number. It sure is possible if i code each credit card number one by one, but what if I have to hide the first 12 numbers for many credit cards? Is there a more convenient way of settling this ?

Help is greatly appreciated!

Ps. I'm kind of new to technology, I'm sorry for any problems caused :(

Comment: Pss. Im working on SQL Server 2008, my bad.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what your desired result is. Do you want to mask the first 12 digits and show the rest no matter the length, or do you want to always show 4 digits and mask all before the last four?

Comment: I want to always show the last 4 digits and mask the first few digits. Because not all credit card has 16 digits, some have 15 digits, thus I would only like to reveal the last 4 digits

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically determine where to cut the string based on it's length, then use `REPLICATE` to pad by the correct amount.

```
DECLARE @cc VARCHAR(16) = '1234123412341234'
DECLARE @len INT
SELECT @len = LEN(@cc)
DECLARE @ss VARCHAR(4) 
SELECT @ss =  SUBSTRING(@cc, LEN(@cc)-3, 4)
SELECT REPLICATE('X', @len-4) + @ss
```

Output:

> XXXXXXXXXXXX1234

This is obviously not a PCI-compliant way of dealing with credit card data.

You could chain these statements together to use them in a larger SELECT statement. You could even define a [scalar valued function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx) that lets you call it without the hassle.

A slightly cleaner version of this (without the variable declarations I put in for sake of example):

```
SELECT REPLICATE('X', LEN(@cc)-4) + SUBSTRING(@cc, LEN(@cc)-3, 4)
```

But I would suggest using Mr. Gibbs version as it using the `RIGHT` function to simplify it even more.

Comment: I have not learned till the extent of using replicate, I guess it's too complex for me...

Comment: @Nonononosir It's just MS's fancy way of saying "Repeat". It just repeats the character given as the first argument as many times as specified in the second. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're querying:

```
SELECT REPLICATE('x', LEN(ccnumber) - 4) + RIGHT(ccnumber, 4))
FROM ...
```

- `REPLICATE` repeats the string *n* times.
- `RIGHT` takes the *n* rightmost characters from the string.

---

For SQL 2012 onward I'd recommend the safer `CONCAT` to assemble the string:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    REPLICATE('x', LEN(ccnumber) - 4),
    RIGHT(ccnumber, 4))
FROM ...
```

- `CONCAT` concatenates two strings; the `+` operator also does this but `CONCAT` will never treat the values as numbers and try to add them.

Comment: `concat` was introduced in 2012 if memory serves me right, so you will have to do the concatenation the old fashioned way.

Comment: Good catch - I missed that "2008" tag. I'll fix.